How to run multiple files from one file in parallel?
Let's say I have a php file named get_data.php Now I am running this file in cronjob passing a parameter like php get_data.php 1. Now if there is 25 parameters then I have to run this file 25 times like
0 * * * * PHP get_data.php 1
0 * * * * PHP get_data.php 2
0 * * * * PHP get_data.php 3
0 * * * * PHP get_data.php 4
.
.
.
0 * * * * PHP get_data.php 25

Now I am looking for a solution to manage this easily. I want to make file all.php and running it on cronjob. in all.php I want to run all the get_data.php file.
There are some ways to do this but it doesn't work in my case.

Include all get_data.php files in the all.php file. This will run get_data.php sequentially, but I want to run it parallelly.

call all get_data.php files parallelly with curl_multi but that will use my webserver and it may cause a timeout issue. I want to run these files in cli


Sorry if I don't make the question clear.

You can make cron run ie bssh script that then starts multiple php scripts ie with nohup or &. Or you can use pcntl_fork() (see this then).

For such a simple command, you can use one line of bash command:
0 * * * *  bash -c "for i in {1..25}; do PHP get_data.php \$i & done"

